# MYSQL with Where and Like And not in

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I compare two tables and output the values there was not in the rows.

```
    SELECT one, two FROM `table1` WHERE `two` NOT IN 
(SELECT `two2` FROM `table2`) AND `one` NOT IN (SELECT `one1` FROM `table2`)
```

How can i add a like... like row '%two' not in '%two2'?

i like to check:

```
SELECT one, two FROM table1 WHERE LIKE %two NOT IN (SELECT LIKE %two2 FROM table2)
```

because in this tables are from time to time a 0 at first place but this i must fade out

I have no variables only the row names. Is any way i can do that?

Comment: Do you have a reference field between `table1` and `table2`? Because I think you need to add this condition in the inner queries, something like: `(SELECT two2 FROM table2 WHERE table1.two = table2.tow2)` - **Maybe this will work:** `SELECT one, two FROM table1 WHERE two NOT IN (SELECT two2 FROM table2 WHERE table1.two = table2.two2 ) AND one NOT IN (SELECT one1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.one = table2.one1 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may invert your condition and use tricky `LEFT JOIN` instead. Then, your query will look like this:

```
SELECT one, two FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON
    `table1`.`one` = `table2`.`one1`
    OR `table1`.`two` = `table2`.`two2`
    -- List others field comparasion using OR here --
WHERE `table2`.`one1` IS NULL;
```

That approach will help you reduce the number of subqueries and improve performance and readability greatly.

Comment: i mean i like to check: 
SELECT one, two FROM `table1` WHERE LIKE `%two` NOT IN 
(SELECT LIKE `%two2` FROM `table2`)
because in this tables are from time to time a 0 at first place but this i must  fade out

Comment: Then, you may modify `ON` clause and use `LIKE` operator instead of `=` and receive 

    `table2`.`one1` LIKE CONCAT('%', `table1`.`one`)

Comment: ok i test it and modify. i dont have now a reference field between the tables. i make that. thanks!